# PyQt - Two Listviews incorrectly using the same Model

Tags: listview, pyqt

I have a feeling this might be a trivial question, but I'm stumped.

I have two listViews and I thought I was creating a model for each listView but it appears as though the listviews are using the same model. The contents, which should only be displayed in listViewA is also displayed in listViewB. How can I rectify this so they have their own models and they show the correct contents?

Here's the code I'm running from the **init** method in the window class:

```
self.modelA = ListModel()
self.modelB = ListModel()
self.listViewA.setModel(self.modelA)
self.listViewB.setModel(self.modelB)
```

I have methods for refreshing the contents of the models

```
def refreshA(self):


    self.modelA.removeRows(0, self.modelA.rowCount(QtCore.QModelIndex()), QtCore.QModelIndex())


    ... # populate modelA

    self.listViewA.update()


def refreshB(self):


    self.modelB.removeRows(0, self.modelB.rowCount(QtCore.QModelIndex()), QtCore.QModelIndex())


    ... # populate modelB

    self.listViewB.update()
```

and I run both refresh methods from a refresh button

def on_actionRefresh_triggered(self,checked=None):
        if checked is None: return

```
    self.refreshA()
    self.refreshB()
```

and prior to showing the window

def showWindow(self):

```
    self.refreshA()
    self.refreshB()
    self.show()
```

Comment: Can you post your model? I think you're using class attributes to store the data.

Answer (score 0):

It was trivial after all. All that was needed was to create two specific data models, one for each listview. Inheritance did the trick here.